# How to know the type of an jQuery object?

Tags: jquery

I need to detect whether it's a `<option>` or something else

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [`is`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/is#expr) method to check whether a jQuery object matches a selector.

For example:

```
var isOption = someObj.is('option');
```

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
yourObject[0].tagName;
```

Since a jQuery object is an array of objects you can retrieve the underlying DOM element by indexing that array.  Once you have the element you can retrieve its `tagName`.  (Note that even if you have one element you will still have an array, albeit an array of one element).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to check the [`.nodeName`](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/prop_node_nodename.asp) property of the element.  Something about like this should work for you:

```
// a very quick little helper function
$.fn.getNodeName = function() { 
  // returns the nodeName of the first matched element, or ""
  return this[0] ? this[0].nodeName : "";
};

var $something = $(".something");

alert($something.getNodeName());
```

I generally prefer using jQuery's [`.is()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/is) to test what something is.

> Checks the current selection against
>   an expression and returns true, if at
>   least one element of the selection
>   fits the given expression.

```
if ($something.is("option")) {
  // work with an option element
}
```