# Jquery - Finding what element $(this) is

Tags: jquery, elementname

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can jQuery provide the tag name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532331/can-jquery-provide-the-tag-name)

Hi!

This question is so basic i am ashamed asking but i tried to find the answer for 30 minutes without any result.

How do i find out what kind of element has been clicked in the code below.

```
$('*').click(function (event) {
 var this_element = $(this).???;
 return false;
})
```

What i am looking for is to have the this_element variable set to 'a' if it's a link, 'p' if it's a paragraph 'div' if...

Thanks!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341900/how-can-i-determine-the-element-type-of-a-matched-element-in-jquery
and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532331/can-jquery-provide-the-tag-name
and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864151/how-to-know-the-type-of-an-jquery-object
...

Comment: by the way, should include `event.stopPropagation();` to stop your click from being passed along to parent elements for no good reason. see the api docs: http://api.jquery.com/get/

Comment: @ghoppe - `return false;` in jQuery event handles `.stopPropagation()` and `.preventDefault()`

Comment: ah, did not realize! Thank you @gnarf.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('*').click(function (event) {
    var this_element = this.tagName.toLowerCase();
    return false;
});
```

The `this` pointer refers to the actual element being acted upon.  As part of the DOM Level 2 core, all DOM elements have a property called [`.tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.tagName).

Comment: Be sure to `.toLowerCase()` some browsers implement all caps for `.tagName` while others don't.

Comment: It really depends on what you're doing with the tag name.  It may not matter.  But fair enough, I'll make the change.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(this).get(0).tagName;
```

Comment: um, -1 for what? it works: http://jsbin.com/akohe/edit

Comment: donno, but it is somewhat redundant - `$(this).get(0)` should always equal `this`.

Comment: only true in this specific case (clicking on an element). $(this) may contain more than one DOM element…

Comment: Well, sure... If `this` happened to be a selector string, or an array of elements, or some such. But that's not really relevant to *this* question.

Comment: I just get undefined values when I use this